# How can I show a decimal in a text field?

Tags: c#, double, decimal, pi

I am creating a simple console application that shows the value of PI up to a certain number of decimals. For now, I have written the following code:

```
namespace PIApplication
{
  static void Main()
  {
    decimal Pi = Math.PI;
    Console.Writeline("Pi is {0}.", PI);
  }
}
```

The reason I used `{0}` is that I know that this method works when it comes to Booleans but I can only assume that the 0 should be changed to something else. Can someone explain how this would work in my case?

Furthermore, I am getting an error that the system can not convert type double to decimal. I assume that this refers to the value that is defined as PI. What would I have to do to convert it from one type to the other? Do I even have to?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the constant `PI` is defined in `System.Math`:

```
public const double PI = 3.14159
```

Try:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double Pi = Math.PI; 
        Console.WriteLine("Pi is {0}.", Pi); 
    }
```

[Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=VS.100%29.aspx): Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has a greater precision and a smaller range, which makes it suitable for financial and monetary calculations.

Answer (score 1):

No need to store PI, unless you want to store it at a given precision.

```
int givenPrecision = 10;
Console.WriteLine("Pi is {0}.", Math.PI.ToString("0." + new String('#', givenPrecision)));
```

This will give 3.1415926536.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly convert??

```
 namespace PIApplication{
  static void Main()
  {
    decimal Pi = (decimal)Math.PI;
    Console.Writeline("Pi is {0}.", Pi);
  }
}
```

*emphasized text*